# Run the service periodically everyday and stop if the event is detected

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-notifications

**Problem**:I have application that requires a service to run everyday checking for a user activity(for example completion of a task).The service runs every 2 seconds and if the task is completed then it stops. It then starts on next day 12:00:00 AM. User has time from 12 AM to 11:59:59 PM to complete the task. I also want to send the notifications to the user alerting him/her about the remaining time. Like 'n' hours remaining. If a user completes a task then I have to send only one notification indicating task completed and stop the service for the day.

**Attempt**:I have tried to look into [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling) and [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) but not getting the flow in which I should call my functions. So far I did this:

A class for service: **NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    public NotificationService() {
        super();
    }

    private Timer mTimer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //check for the occurance of the event here
            // checkEventOccured();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 2000, 2 * 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I also created a broadcastReceiver class:**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //Should I build the notification here?
       //Then start the service from here?

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Not sure if this is correct.Logic to schedule alarm everyday till 11:59:59 starting from 12 AM 
        while(true){
              //AlarmManager
              AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             Intent notification_intent = new Intent(getContext(), BootReceiver.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("dummy",10);
            notification_intent.putExtras(bundle);

            int i = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), i, notification_intent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000 * 60*60*24, pendingIntent);

        }
    }

}
```

Now where do I start service for the first time? Any help to make me understand flow is appreciated.

Comment: "The service runs every 2 seconds" -- your code will work for a few minutes, then stop as soon as the device goes into sleep mode. Even if you address that with a wakelock, that will not work on Android 6.0+, courtesy of Doze mode. And, on Android 8.0+, your service will run for about a minute before it it stopped. That's in part because doing work every 2 seconds in the background is horrible for the battery.

Comment: Okay I will edit the timings.Apart from that how should I make calls? And from which methods?